# Yocto patch for DEPEND fix

Tags: yocto, patch

Is there any way to write a yocto recipe patch that change the `DEPEND` variable before dependencies checking happen?

For example, I want to change

`DEPENDS = "eudev"` to `DEPENDS = "udev"`

But it leads to an issue related to dependencies.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the stackoverflow! Please be more specific. What you trying to do, that you need to change the variable. Also if you have an issues occuring, then show it's outputs. Make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEPENDS_remove = "eudev"
DEPENDS_append = "udev"
```

Comment: Hi @Oleksandr -- thank you for the contribution. Can you add an explanation of what your code is doing to help future readers and the author?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `DEPENDS` again in a bbappend for your recipe.

```
DEPENDS = "udev"
```

And then you're good to go! If there's more than one dependency, either set `DEPENDS` to all the original but swap udev or eudev or go for Oleksandr's answer. Still in a bbappend for the recipe:

```
DEPENDS_remove = "eudev"
DEPENDS += "udev" # or DEPENDS_append = " udev" <= don't forget the leading space!
```

This will effectively remove `eudev` from your `DEPENDS` and add `udev` to it. Please note that anything appearing in `_remove` if **definitive**, you can**not** undo it.